# PHP Error, how can i resolve?

Tags: php

[image]

i have uploaded a site to hosting, this site have 3 sub sites inside of it, and when i browse it, the above error is shown. which file should i modify? My Config File code is as below.

```php
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

// Site Name & Title
 define('SITE_NAME','SREE SHIRIDI SAI HIGH SCHOOL');
 define('SITE_TITLE','SREE SHIRIDI SAI HIGH SCHOOL');

 // Site Path ...
 define('SITE_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'medha/skool');
 define('ADMIN_PATH',SITE_PATH.'/admin');
 define('CSS_PATH',SITE_PATH.'/css');
 define('PHP_PATH',SITE_PATH.'/php');
 define('JS_PATH',SITE_PATH.'/js');
 define('IMAGES_PATH',SITE_PATH.'/imageS');
 define('INC_PATH',SITE_PATH.'/inc');
 define('LIB_PATH',SITE_PATH.'/lib');

 // Site URL's ...
 define('SITE_URL','http://working.fssolutions.in/medha/skool');
 define('ADMIN_URL',SITE_URL.'/admin');
 define('CSS_URL',SITE_URL.'/css');
 define('PHP_URL',SITE_URL.'/php');
 define('JS_URL',SITE_URL.'/js');
 define('IMAGES_URL',SITE_URL.'/images');
 define('INC_URL',SITE_URL.'/inc');
 define('LIB_URL',SITE_URL.'/lib');
 //echo JS_URL;


 // Database Connections Do not Modify Below....
 define('DB_HOST','localhost');
 define('DB_USER','root');
 define('DB_PWD','');
define('DB_NAME','');
define('DB_TYPE','');
?>
```

Comment: `define('SITE_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/medha/skool');` add a leading slash before medha

Comment: Show us the line number `2`in `index.php`.

Comment: Its done, working file now